# 06 Chevy Aveo 5-speed Manual - every gear I put in it's like it is in neutral

Tags: chevrolet, clutch-cylinder, aveo, clutch-hydraulics

I have an 06 Chevy Aveo 5 speed manual transmission and about 200,000 mi on it I just bought it so I don't really know too much about the history the problem I'm having right now is that I could put the clutch in to start the vehicle put it in gear and I could let the clutch out in gear and the car still stays running the car will not move when I put the clutch in any of the five years it acts like it's in neutral and just revs up but won't move

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, your clutch is dead. You're going to need a replacement.